DHT11 sensor giving NAN for Temperature and Humidity
I am working on an Arduino Smartwatch with an RTC Module and a DHT11 Temperature Sensor. I have not connected the RTC Module yet since I am receiving an NAN for the Temperature and Humidity. I have checked and I have no loose wires on my breadboard. I am using an SH1106 OLED Screen with an Arduino Uno and a 10K Ohm Potentiometer.
Below is the code:
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_SH1106.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SH1106 display(OLED_RESET);

#define DHT_TYPE DHT11
#define DHT_PIN 2
DHT HT(DHT_PIN, DHT_TYPE);
float humi;
float tempC;
float tempF;

int current_menu;
int menu_knob_state;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  display.begin(SH1106_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
 
  display.display();
  display.clearDisplay();

  HT.begin();
}

void mainmenu()
{ 
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK, WHITE);
  display.print("Archimedes V1 - Menu ");
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setCursor(15, 20);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.print("12:00:00");
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(35, 40);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.print("01/01/1900");
  display.display();
  // delay(500);
}

void tempmenu(float tempC, float tempF, float humi){

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.setTextColor(BLACK, WHITE);
  display.print("Archimedes V1 - Temp.");
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setCursor(3, 20);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.print(tempF);
  display.setCursor(40, 20);
  display.print("F");
  display.setCursor(73, 20);
  display.print(tempC);
  display.setCursor(110, 20);
  display.print("C");
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(20, 40);
  display.print("Humidity:");
  display.setCursor(80, 40);
  display.print(humi);
  display.print("%");
  display.display();
  // delay(500);
}

void loop()
{
  menu_knob_state = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(menu_knob_state);

  humi = HT.readHumidity();
  tempC = HT.readTemperature();
  tempF = HT.readTemperature(true);
  
  if(menu_knob_state <= 256){
    current_menu = 0;
    mainmenu();
  } else if((menu_knob_state > 256)){
    current_menu=1;
    tempmenu(tempC, tempF, humi);
  }
} 

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"I am receiving an NAN for the Temperature", where exactly you received NAN? you means tempC = HT.readTemperature() where the tempC is NAN? or you means the oled display shown as NAN?

@hcheung On the OLED Screen, the output observed is NAN. There is a graphical output, but when showing the temperature and humidity, it shows NAN.

There are a few simple debugging steps you could try. What if you do Serial.println(tempC);, will it shown NAN? If it able to show a floating point value on Serial Monitor, that means the display.print() might not support floating point, in that case, you should be able to display the value by converting it to string with display.print(String(tempC).c_str());. If the Serial.println(tempC) was unable to display a valid value, that's means there are something wrong either with the hardware or the configuration and initialisation before HT.begin() are not correctly setup.

@hcheung I followed your potential solution, and I recieved several artifacts on my OLED Screen. The screen glitched out repeatedly, I now believe the error relates to a broken DHT Sensor, as my sensor is 3+ years old, and has been used countless times.

I have edited down an example from Adafruit for the DHT11 sensor, and have it working on an Arduino UNO. You could try this simple code with your setup to help narrow down what is going wrong. I have found that if I set the sensor to DH22 in the code rather than DHT11, it returns NAN - so it is possible that you have got the wrong sensor. Some sensors are labelled almost unreadably. I also found that if the sensor output pin was not connected I again got a NAN response. So there is a possibility that you have a bad connection, or that you are not using the same output pin as in your code. Finally most sensors contain an internal pullup resistor. If yours does not, a 10k resistor to Vcc should fix this.
// Written by ladyada, public domain

// REQUIRES the following Arduino libraries:
// - DHT Sensor Library: https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library
// - Adafruit Unified Sensor Lib: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor

#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 7

#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
//#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("DHTxx test!"));

  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(2000);

  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.println(F("% "));
  Serial.print(F("Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.println(F(" C "));
}


I used this code and got a string of artifacts from the DHT Sensor.

If you are using this code, and have connected the sensor correctly, and you are not getting sensible data then you do not have a working DHT11 sensor. If you are certain that your sensor is a DHT11, then you should try a replacement. They are not expensive.
